# How can I use a network interface as internet access in hostapd

Tags: networking, wifi, network-interface, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

I created a `hostapd` WiFi hotspot and now I want to use my phone via USB tethering as an internet source.

I don't want to use a bridge because my phone isn't always connected, the hotspot should always exist.

Is there a config line for `/etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf` or something? I tried RaspAP but this feature is paid only.

I want to set it up manually.

Comment: but in this case using a bridge device is the *exact* right thing: you can let hostapd always work with the bridge device, and only actually add the phone network interface to the bridge when connected.

Comment: But I want to use my Raspberry for DHCP, when I'm using a bridge, my phone is the DHCP server - if it isn't connected I can't connect to my WiFi. Android sais Unable to obtain IP address or something like that.

Comment: hm I don't understand – maybe we're having a different understanding of "bridge". I mean a linux bridge network device, like you can set up e.g. with `brctl`; I think you mean an operational mode of an AP?

Comment: but if you don't let your hostapd be a DHCP server, then there will be nothing to assign network addresses when clients connect, which will probably lead to a lot of confusion. What's the advantage of restricting yourself to relying on the phone's DHCP server?

Comment: That is my problem. If I use my bridge `br0` in my config file I'm not able to connect to the wifi unless my phone is connected.

Comment: yes. You need to run a DHCP server. Something needs to assign IP addresses to your clients. The phone's DHCP server is only useful for the network connection between your machine and the phone.

Comment: I'm running `dhcpcd`

Comment: ah I see, but for some reason you seem to be forwarding DHCP requests to your phone when that is connected? That'd be something you can block with nftables :)

Comment: If I block them, will they go to my DHCP server on the Raspberry Pi? Or do I need to redirect the requests somehow?

Comment: you just block DHCP requests coming from the Wifi and going anywhere but to your dhcpd. Or, as you say, you don't bridge, but route, but then you need to adjust the route to always go through the changing IP address of your phone.

Comment: Can you write me an example command? I am completely new to networking. Do you use `iptables` for that?